# Squid stale-while-revalidate not working when max-age=0

Tags: squid, reverse-proxy

Squid 2.7 always reaches backend, expected is to reach backend using stale-while-revalidate only when cache expires, not when client triggers max-age=0.

Script:

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=10, stale-if-error=200, stale-while-revalidate=500');
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

sleep(2);
die("OK");
```

And squid config:

```
# http_port public_ip:port accel defaultsite= default hostname, if not provided
http_port 80 accel defaultsite=mydomain.com

# IP and port of your main application server (or multiple)
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8000 0 no-query allow-miss originserver name=main

# Do not tell the world that which squid version we're running
httpd_suppress_version_string on

# Remove the Caching Control header for upstream servers
header_access Cache-Control deny all
#header_access Last-Modified deny all

# log all incoming traffic in Apache format
logformat combined %>a %ui %un [%tl] "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %Hs %<st "%{Referer}>h" "%{User-Agent}>h" %Ss:%Sh
access_log /usr/local/squid/var/logs/squid.log combined all

cache_effective_user squid

refresh_pattern . 10080 90% 999999 ignore-no-cache override-expire ignore-private

icp_port 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846107/how-to-use-in-squid-2-7-the-3-1-feature-ignore-cc

---

Well, after trying all alternatives, I modified the source code to implement the feature.

I changed in the **Squid-2.7-stable9** the file **src/refresh.c**:*282*:

```
282:    if (request) {
```

for

```
282:    if (request && FALSE) {
```

---

They do something like that in the 3.X to implement ignoreCc:

```
269:    if (request && !request->flags.ignore_cc) {
```

Worked as expected.